# Serialize struct with union and struct in it

Tags: c, serialization

```
typedef struct { 
 union { 
  char a[8]; 
  struct { 
    unsigned long z; 
    unsigned long o; 
  } ss; 
 } ss; 
} st3;
```

I have this struct in memory I want to serialize it to struct I can use, How do I serialize it correctly?
Thanks.

Comment: Not possible. You need to know which branch of the union to take.

Comment: note that since C99, anonymous structs and unions are permitted, so the `ss` names are redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As n.m. remarks in his comment, you must know what the union contains. Thereto it is common to define the struct like:

```
typedef struct { 
 int union_type;
 union { 
  char a[8]; 
  struct { 
    unsigned long z; 
    unsigned long o; 
  } ss; 
 } ss; 
} st3;
```

where `union_type` indicates whether the union contains the char array or the struct. If you know this, you can serialize the struct and the receiver can re-construct it because before serializing the union, you output the `union_type` and then the member in use (the chars or struct).

There is one alternative: you determine the largest component of the union (not relevant here) and output that as binary bytes, e.g. as a list of `\x1a\x1b...`. Then you don't need to know what was in the union. If the receiver re-assembles it like that, it delivers a perfectly transferred object to the functional program, and let's hope that knows what the union contains... One note: this method requires the endianness of both machines to be the same, otherwise the longs will be re-assembled wrong.